# How to build a model using NaiveBayes in teradataml?

Tags: python, teradata

How to build a model using NaiveBayes in Teradataml:
1. Input data is a teradata table

Answer (score 0):

1. Import following:

   import teradataml
   from teradataml.context.context import *
   from teradataml.dataframe.dataframe import DataFrame
   from teradataml.analytics.mle.NaiveBayesPredict import NaiveBayesPredict
2. Create a database context for connecting to desired teradata database

   con = create_context(host="hostname", username="Specify username", password="Specify password")

2, Create a dataframe for input table that resides in teradata

```
nb_input_train = DataFrame.from_table("nb_input_train")
nb_input_test = DataFrame.from_table("nb_input_test")
```

3. Train:
   naivebayes_train = NaiveBayes(formula="col1 ~ col2 + col3 + col4 + col5",data=nb_input_train)
4. Predict

   naivebayes_predict_result = NaiveBayesPredict(newdata=nb_input_test,modeldata=naivebayes_train,id_col="id",formula="col1 ~ col2 + col3 + col4 + col5",responses = ["val1","val2","val3"])

**Tip:**
In order to view the sqlmr query set print_sqlmr_query to true

```
from teradataml.options.display import display
display.print_sqlmr_query = True
```